# AngularJS 1.2 $http seems to cache POST requests when no data is passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angularjs-http

I'm having an issue with AngularJS 1.2 POST requests using `$http` service.

On a button click, I trigger a POST request like so:

```
$http.post('my/url').success(function(responseText) {
    // Do something
    console.log(responseText);
});
```

My problem is, if I click twice on the button and the first callback hasn't fired yet, only one HTTP request is issued, but my callback is fired twice (with the same data as a parameter).

If I explicitely add cache: false:

```
$http.post('my/url', {cache: false}).success(function(responseText) {
    // Do something
    console.log(responseText);
});
```

Then two requests are issued as I expected.

It looks like a bug to me. Why would anybody want to cache a POST request? Moreover, the [AngularJS documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$http#caching) specifies that we have to pass cache: true if we want to activate the cache for GET requests. Which sounds like it is inactive by default, and not active at all for POST requests (which would make sense to me).

Is there a way to deactivate the cache once and for all, for every request, on the 1.2 branch? I didn't find any.

**EDIT**

I misused `$http.post`. The second parameter is not the options map, but rather the data to send to the server. According to the documentation, this parameter is mandatory. So I can execute this:

```
$http.post('my/url', {'anything': 'anything'}).success(function(responseText) {
    // Do something
    console.log(responseText);
});
```

And it works as expected.

So the real question is: why is the `data` parameter mandatory for a `$http.post` call to work properly? I feel like I am missing something about HTTP. I already have everything I need in the URL (something like `company/company_id/employee`) and I don't need any additional data.

Comment: I'm curious: is the URL you're POSTing to on the same domain as your web app or another?

Comment: Since no one else has experienced this problem it seems bold to speculate about a bug. Maybe in your `$http` configuration caching is turned on as default.

Comment: @marck: yes, the URL is on the same domain as my web app.

@zeroflagL: this piece of code has been live for 8 or 9 months now, and this is the first time I came across this problem. It is actually quite difficult to reproduce since the callback usually gets called pretty quickly. I had to add a sleep() on the server side to be able to reproduce it.
I searched for `$http` configuration in my code but wasn't able to find anything about it. And it looks like there is no way to configure caching by default with Angular 1.2(.16)

Comment: @zeroflagL: I din't find any cache configuration in my own code. But maybe some library I'm using is doing that. I'm going to have a look.

Comment: I took a look into the sources and angular only caches GET requests, no matter what. Maybe an interceptor is cancelling the request.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. In the meanwhile, I figured out I misused `$http.post`. I edited my question.

Comment: So it's working as expected now? It seems that the data parameter should be optional, but you can use an empty object literal there, I think. Right?

Comment: Nope, if I use an empty object literal, the strange caching behavior remains. The object must have at least one property, and then it behaves as expected.

Comment: Seems to me that if you are posting an empty body, you shouldn't be posting. The point of posting is to send along an object (post body). Without that object, you are technically doing a PUT or even GET request. I'd change your request method. Doesn't answer your question, but makes it irrelevant.

Comment: That's a bit odd to me: I can't see what's wrong with creating an empty object like a new employee. Well, not empty, it is linked to a company, but the company id is already in the query string : company/{id}/employee. 
Then the user would give him a name, lastname, etc. triggering PUT requests. Maybe I should only POST the new employee when these properties are already typed in. But in an auto-saving context, I fell like it would complexify the saving code quite a bit. Maybe this whole this is wrong though.